# Can the EHLO or HELO SMTP command be issued more than once?

Tags: smtp

In conforming rfc5321 SMTP implementations, can the EHLO or HELO command be issued more than once? If so, what effects should that have on the connection state?

All section 4.1.1.1 mentions is

> A client SMTP SHOULD start an SMTP session by issuing the EHLO command. [...] In any event, a client MUST issue HELO or EHLO before starting a mail transaction. These commands, and a "250 OK" reply to one of them, confirm that both the SMTP client and the SMTP server are in the initial state, that is, there is no transaction in progress and all state tables and buffers are cleared.

That implies (though doesn't spell out) that if a transaction is in progress, sending an EHLO or HELO command is a sequencing error.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the implication that the server must be in the initial state, this is allowed per section 4.1.4:

> An EHLO command MAY be issued by a client later in the session.  If it is issued after the session begins and the EHLO command is acceptable to the SMTP server, the SMTP server MUST clear all buffers and reset the state exactly as if a RSET command had been issued.

So the part about it "confirming" that both client and server are in the initial state must be read to mean that after the EHLO response has been received, the server must then be in the initial state, and the client must also be in the initial state (and an unexpected initial state on the client side may be the reason for the EHLO to begin with)